# MediaPlayer.create() method is giving me errors?

Tags: android

I keep getting a "cannot resolve method create(android.view.View.OnclickListner,?)" squiggly lines. What am I doing wrong the Methods seem to be correct? yet my application get errors??

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.001);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.001);
```

to

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity .this,R.raw.001);
```

Since you are inside of a listener, `this` refers to the `onClick`. You need to use the `Activity` `Context`

Comment: Try cleaning your project. And please don't change your OP

Answer (score -2):

because of this line :

```
 play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

change it to this :

```
play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

also you dont need   `@Override`